# Python downloaded data in table form

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code that is downloading data from table and output that on cmd. I want to know if the same data can be downloaded in the same structure of table like in rows and columns?
This is what i have tried.

code:

```
import urllib
import re
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ["http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members", "http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=ME","http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=CE"]
i = 0


while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    soup = bs(htmltext)
    tables  = soup.find_all('table', attrs = {'border': '0' , 'width' : '100%' , 'cellpadding': '10'})
    head = soup.find_all('h2' , attrs = {'class' : 'title style3'})
    ree = tables.find_all('tr')
    hea = head.find_all('big').find_all('strong')
    datasets = []
    q = []
    s = []
    t = hea.get_text()
    q.append(t)

    for b in ree:
        x = [td.get_text() for td in b.find_all('td')]
        dataset = [strong.get_text() for strong in b.find('td').find('a').find_all('strong')]
        datasets.append(dataset)
        q.append(x) 
print q
i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think many people would recommend the use of the pandas library when working with tabular data.  For well structured HTML, you can just blindly use pandas read_html.

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members")
dataframe = tables[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got well formatted output. @thomas tu